# Конвертировать дату в другой формат

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Как конвертировать дату в формате `YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]` (например `2017-09-21T21:00:00.000Z`) в формат  `DD.MM.YYYY` (например `11.05.2017`)?
Можно через `moment`.

Comment: И как из 21.09.2017 должно получаться 11.05.2017?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую использовать маленькую и удобную либо dateformat
В этом случае код будет выглядеть как:

`var d = new Date('2017-09-21T21:00:00.000Z');
dateformat(d, 'DD.MM.YYYY')`

Вот ссылка на доку:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat

Answer (score 1):

Например так :

```js
var a = new Date('2017-09-21T21:00:00.000Z');

var res = [
  addLeadZero(a.getDate()),
  addLeadZero(a.getMonth() + 1),
  a.getFullYear()
].join('.');

console.log(res);

function addLeadZero(val) {
  if (+val < 10) return '0' + val;
  return val;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [`.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString):

```js
var options = {
  day: 'numeric',
  month: 'numeric',
  year: 'numeric'
}

function getDate(str) {
  var date = new Date(str);
  return date.toLocaleString('ru', options)
}

console.log(getDate('2017-09-21T21:00:00.000Z'));
```